# SQL Server auto populated calendar

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am not sure whether its possible or not in SQL Server.

How to create an auto-populated calender with year, month, week and day in SQL Server for the years 2015 and 2016.

Thanks

Comment: You just have to define a `Calendar` table and then write an `INSERT` statement that inserts the values. There's no "built-in magic" to have such tables "auto-generated" - if you need them, it's **your job** to create and fill them

Comment: Watch it: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19191577/t-sql-function-to-generate-calendar-table][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19191577/t-sql-function-to-generate-calendar-table